# How can we dynamically set db.default.url in application.conf file?

Tags: jdbc, playframework, playframework-2.0, database-connection

I have a host name and a port, set in env variable and I want my db.default.url to be like this,

**`db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://${DB_PORT_3306_TCP_HOST}:${DB_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT}/database_name"`**

But this doesn't workout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never tried it myself but I guess it should look like this in the `application.conf`:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://"${host}":"${port}"/database_name"
```

And you'd start your project with something like this:

```
/path/to/bin/<project-name> -Dport=1234 -Dhost=127.0.0.1
```

You can learn a lot about the schema of Play's config from [this doc](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/HOCON.md).